# Stubbing an AWS Resource to raise a ClientError

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, stubbing, botocore

I have the following python code snippet (assuming the update_item arguments are valid):

```
#foo.py
def update_table(value):
 dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
     try:
         table = dynamodb.Table("test-table")
         response = table.update_item(Key=('value' : value)
     except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as err:
         return None
     return response
```

Now, I would like to write a unit test that test whether this function returns None when a valid arugments are passed but a ClientError is thrown.

I mocked out a DynamoDB Table in a setUp function as shown:

```
#test_foo.py
@mock_dynamodb2
class TestUpdateTable(unittest.TestCase):
    

    def setUp(self):
        self.dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
        
        # Creates a Mock Table
        self.table = self.dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName='test-table',
            KeySchema=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'value',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'
                },
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'value',
                    'AttributeType': 'S'
                },
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
        }
        )
```

and in my test function under this class:

```
def test_returns_none(self):
        stubber = Stubber(self.dynamodb.meta.client)
        stubber.add_client_error('update_item')
        
        stubber.activate()
        
        response = foo.update_table("123")
        stubber.deactivate()

        self.assertEqual(response, None)
```

Now, I expect this to properly stub out the table and raise a ClientError when calling the function to update the table. However, it seems like a ClientError is not raised and the response from the function that I'm testing is not = None as a ClientError is not raised.

Anyone knows the reason for that? And how can I implement this test in a way so that the mock table will raise a ClientError and return None?